# Custom field with embedded html in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, mp3, kibana, kibana-4

I have a field in elasticsearch index with a mp3 filename, i want to create a custom field that shows a player with a formatted url and adding the filename stored in elasticsearch. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a scripted field : https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-beta-3-now-more-filtery

Something like that `"url/"+doc["filename"].value`